# Determine if string contains more than one word?

Tags: python

If for example:

```
def matching_names(name1, name2):

""" (list of str, str) -> list of str
```

and name1 has the form 'firstname lastname', 
what do I do if I want it to return the list of name1 that has the firstname equal to name2?

ex)

```
matching_names(['sarah james', 'rebecca black', 'rebecca kim'], 'rebecca')
```

> > > ['rebecca black', 'rebecca kim']

Answer (score 0):

```
def matching_names(name1, name2):
    a = []
    for name in name1:
        if name.split(" ")[0] == name2:
            a.append(name)
    return a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results = []
for entry in name1:
  if entry.split()[0] == name2:
    results.append(entry)

return results
```